# Freemarker getServletContext().getMimeType(filename)

Tags: java, freemarker, spark-java

I am trying to get servlet context in Freemarker \ Spark and my `getServletContext()` is returning me `null`.

```
ServletContext servletContext = request.raw().getSession().getServletContext();
File titleImage = (File)post.get("titleimage");

resp.setHeader("Content-Type", servletContext.getMimeType(titleImage.getName()));   
resp.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(titleImage.length()));   
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""+titleImage.getName()+"\"");
```

Comment: Where does FreeMarker come into this?

Comment: Yes you are right, its spark and free marker related question because I need to get the session for free marker template but its from Spark

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ServletContext servletContext = request.raw().getSession().getServletContext();
```

do this:

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
```

Comment: There no such request.getSession() method because this request of type Spark.Request and I tried below but it came null.                ServletContext servletContext = request.raw().getSession().getServletContext();